# Call a FUNCTION from inside a PROCEDURE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Right now, we are migrating a stored procedure from SQL Server to Postgres.

We have a procedure which does some write operations and after that It will call a list function to list all the data currently existing.

```
create or replace procedure public.tree_create()
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
   /* Insertion code goes here. */

    /* return result. */
    select * from public.tree_list();
END;
$$;
```

This will throw error

> [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. Where: PL/pgSQL function public.tree_create() line 4 at SQL statement

So how can we return data by calling the function. FYI: The function is working fine and when we call it using `select * from list_tree()` It will returns the data.

So how exactly can we call FUNCTION inside STORED PROCEDURE to return results? Or is there any other methods to follow?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of the function?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Return result and display it.

Answer (score 2):

Procedures aren't meant to return results. You need to convert it into a function:

```
create or replace function public.tree_create()
  returns table (... same signature as tree_list() ...)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
   /* Insertion code goes here. */

    return query
      select * from public.tree_list();
END;
$$;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from tree_create();
```

Comment: We gone for functions initally. But in some stored procedures in SQL Server, They are using TRANSACTION to commit/rollback etc. So how can we achieve the same using the functions?

Comment: @md-shah: the caller will need to handle the transaction if you really need to return a result. I would probably change the calling code: one call to the procedure to do the insert (and transaction handling) then another call to `tree_list()` afterwards to get the result. It's never a good idea to combine too many responsibilities into a single "module"